# Remove characters from beginning of a string in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I am running a gaming community that used to have a requirement of having a prefix in members usernames. An example would be "RDxBuffalo". We recently decided to get rid of the prefix/tag and now I am looking to remove it from everyone's name. I am assuming the best way of doing this would be via a SQL query and I have been having issues finding the best way to do it.

This is what I am looking for the query to do:

1. Check all usernames in database for any that have "RDx" (some may or may not be capitalized) at the beginning of the name/string.
2. Remove the "RDx" from the beginning of the username.

Any help is appreciated, and an explanation of the query would be amazing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring), the function you are looking for is `SUBSTR()` and the operation to modify a table is `UPDATE`. You can use the `SUBSTR()` function in your `WHERE` clause to find rows that match your criteria:

```
UPDATE your_members_table 
SET member_name = SUBSTR(member_name, 4) --drops first 3 characters
WHERE SUBSTR(member_name, 1, 3) = "RDx"
```

Good luck!

Edit: Add `UPPER()` or `LOWER()` for case-insensitivity:

```
WHERE UPPER(SUBSTR(member_name, 1, 3)) = "RDX"
```

Comment: This is true. Thx for sharing. Nice doc'ng it.

Answer (score 1):

Check the first 3 chacarcters in the `where` clause using the [left() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_left) and convert them to lower case with the lower() function, use the [substring() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) in the `set` clause to return the string from the 4th character:

```
update yourtable set username=substring(username,4) where lower(left(username,3))='rdx'
```

Convert the above statement to a select to see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using an update query.

The where part of the query will be as follows

```
    where lower(name) like 'rdx%'
```

The update part you can use substring functions such as mid().

```
     MID(column_name,start)
```